# Why am i getting a OpenXmlUnknownElement?

Tags: c#, arrays, openxml

This is not really a question since I already have found the reason for this problem[image: Retrieving descendants from OpenXml body]

The descendants are retrieved using this code.

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
namespace Testolini
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var word = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
            word.AddMainDocumentPart();
            word.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
                                                new Body(
                                                    new Paragraph(
                                                        new Run(
                                                            new Paragraph(
                                                                new Run(
                                                                    new Text("test1"))),
                                                            new Paragraph(
                                                                new Run(
                                                                    new Text("test2"))),
                                                            new Paragraph(
                                                                new Run(
                                                                    new Text("test3")))))));
            word.Close();

            using (var memorystream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename)))
            {
                var word2 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memorystream, true);

                var descendants = word2.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants();

                word.Close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you get the same problem. It can be because the XML fil does not validate with the ECMA standard. 
In my case the problem was that i had nested paragraphs.

The problem shows up when I opened the document using bytearray and memorystream. It looks like the elements is validated and if the validation fails it becames an OpenXmlUnknownElement.

If anyone have better explanation and maybe a more precise reason for this problem I would love to learn more about it.

Comment: I think this happens when you alter the document so that it contains children beneath parents that should not be related that way. Is that a possible scenario in your solution?

Comment: yes. In my case you cannot have a paragraph inside a run(/paragraph). i am trying to find a way to perform a validation so that this does not happen.

Comment: This might be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497334.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Run` cannot contain another `Paragraph`.

Here is a list of valid child elements for a `Run`:

> annotationRef (Comment Information Block) 
>   br (Break) 
>   commentReference (Comment Content Reference Mark) 
>   contentPart (Content Part) 
>   continuationSeparator (Continuation Separator Mark) 
>   cr (Carriage Return) 
>   dayLong (Date Block - Long Day Format) 
>   dayShort (Date Block - Short Day Format) 
>   delInstrText (Deleted Field Code) 
>   delText (Deleted Text) 
>   drawing (DrawingML Object) 
>   endnoteRef (Endnote Reference Mark) 
>   endnoteReference (Endnote Reference) 
>   fldChar (Complex Field Character) 
>   footnoteRef (Footnote Reference Mark) 
>   footnoteReference (Footnote Reference) 
>   instrText (Field Code) 
>   lastRenderedPageBreak (Position of Last Calculated Page Break) 
>   monthLong (Date Block - Long Month Format) 
>   monthShort (Date Block - Short Month Format) 
>   noBreakHyphen (Non Breaking Hyphen Character) 
>   object (Embedded Object) 
>   pgNum (Page Number Block) 
>   ptab (Absolute Position Tab Character) 
>   rPr (Run Properties) 
>   ruby (Phonetic Guide) 
>   separator (Footnote/Endnote Separator Mark) 
>   softHyphen (Optional Hyphen Character) 
>   sym (Symbol Character) 
>   t (Text) 
>   tab (Tab Character) 
>   yearLong (Date Block - Long Year Format) 
>   yearShort (Date Block - Short Year Format)

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.run.aspx).

Why do you need "nested" paragraphs?

Comment: I dont. The program autogenerates openxml files, and somewhere in the program the paragraphs got nested which caused my error.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the document is in an invalid state. I think this happens when you alter the document so that it contains children beneath parents that should not be related that way.

This might be of help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497334.aspx